# How to deallocate python multiprocessing managed resources

Tags: python-multiprocessing

If I have a multiprocessing.Manager instance and say I allocate a Queue using the manager, how can I deallocate this queue? I am going to create millions of queues because I will be generating millions of processes (during a few days), so I don't think leaving the Queue without deallocating it is an option.

Maybe I shouldn't create a new queue for each new process? The queues are used to send back the "return result" of each process and I need to know which process returned what. Well, I mean I need to know which input resulted in which output. Should I use a different data structure than a Queue?